# How can I use volumeSlider in NAudio?

Tags: c#, audio, volume, naudio

I'm using **NAudio** library for audio player project. I want to make user control volume-slider like [here](http://s21.postimg.org/r2327qvmf/upload.jpg)

Is there anyone who knows how to use volume-slider in NAudio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NAudioDemo` project included in the source code includes an example of using this slider. Handle the `VolumeChanged` event on the `VolumeSlider`, and then use the `Volume` property to set the volume either on a stream (e.g. the `Volume` property on `SampleChannel`), or directly on the output device (e.g. `WaveOut`)

Comment: I'm setting up Stream volume in slider change command, But the audio is getting hang while slider is being moved.